# Nominatim versus Google's geocoder address aproximation

Tags: mapquest, nominatim

I have been trying to display the details of the route that my program is retrieving, precisely the street names.
I get the route results in gps coordinates and i decided to use MapQuest's Nominatim service for the reverse geocoding, because the limitations on GoogleMaps's service.

However, apparently, nominatim is not doing a very good job. As an example here is a group of coordinates:  48.8730900 2.3273124 which should belong to "15-19 Rue des Mathurins, 75009 Paris, France" as Google correctly indicates. Nominatim retrieves this:

```
streetNames12({"place_id":"12999164","licence":"Data \u00a9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright","osm_type":"node","osm_id":"1227307571","lat":"48.8730597","lon":"2.3269047","display_name":"32, Rue Tronchet, Madeleine, 8th Arrondissement, Paris, Ile-de-France, Metropolitan France, 75008, France","address":{"house_number":"32","road":"Rue Tronchet","suburb":"Madeleine","city_district":"8th Arrondissement","city":"Paris","county":"Paris","state":"Ile-de-France","country":"France","postcode":"75008","country_code":"fr"}})
```

So an address which is completely off, that is not helping at all, you can see that even on the map http://screencast.com/t/VnCHFV40

Do you happen to know of an more precise service with no limitations that could help me?

Edit:
I looked a bit more into this problem, it looks like Nominatim looks for the closest point for which it knows the address, in this case is 48.8730597,2.3269047.

Comment: That address seems to be missing from OpenStreetMap. You can go to http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/48.87302/2.32781&layers=D and add the address and by doing so make Nominatim more usable both for you and everybody else.